# Remove first matching object by property in a list based on another list

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

Suppose we have an array of objects like :

> [     {       LeadId: AABB , Phone: 1234 ,    } ,
>
> {       LeadId: ABCD , Phone: 5678 ,    } ,
>
> {       LeadId: EERR , Phone: 1234 ,    } ,
>
> {       LeadId: FFGG , Phone: 5678 ,    } ]

And an array of phone numbers :

```
[   1234 , 5678 , 6565  ]
```

I want to remove the first occurrence of every phone number in the first list , hence the result would be :

> {         LeadId: EERR , Phone: 1234 ,  } ,
>
> {         LeadId: FFGG , Phone: 5678 ,  }

Assume that `leadsToInsert` is the array that we need to remove occurrences from 
and `phoneNumbers` is the array of phone numbers

I've tried with Underscore :

```
        const leftOvers = _.without(
          leadsToInsert,
          _.find(leadsToInsert, {
            Phone: phoneNumbers
          })
        );
```

When I run this piece of code all the objects in `leadsToInsert` remains and nothing is filtered.

When did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the phones array to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and the use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and delete the current phone from the Set. The [`Set.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete) method returns `true` if the item was removed successfully, and `false` otherwise. So for the first item `!phones.delete()` is `false` (removing the item from the array), while the other items with the same phone would be preserved.

```js
const data = [{ LeadId: 'AABB', Phone: 1234 }, { LeadId: 'ABCD', Phone: 5678 }, { LeadId: 'EERR', Phone: 1234 }, { LeadId: 'FFGG', Phone: 5678 }]
const phones = [1234, 5678, 6565]

const phonesSet = new Set(phones)

const result = data.filter(({ Phone }) => !phonesSet.delete(Phone))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object and set the hash table to `true` for next filtering.

```js
var data = [{ LeadId: 'AABB', Phone: 1234 }, { LeadId: 'ABCD', Phone: 5678 }, { LeadId: 'EERR', Phone: 1234 }, { LeadId: 'FFGG', Phone: 5678 }],
    omitFirst = [1234, 5678, 6565],
    result = data.filter(
        (seen => ({ Phone }) => !omitFirst.includes(Phone) || seen[Phone] || !(seen[Phone] = true))
        ({})
    );

console.log(result);
```